# How can I cast a snapshotView object?

Tags: swift, uiview, casting

I am creating a new view of snapshotView from the target view, but how can I cast on the view I just created? snapshotView returns a `UIView` and I cannot cast it.

My code is here:

```
let targetCopyView = targetView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

`targetView` is a `UITextField` but `targetCopyView` is a `UIView`.
I want to do operations on x but I can't because I can't cast.

```
if let t = targetCopyView as? UITextField{
    print("fefe")
}
```

does not enter `if` block. Actually what I want to do is:

```
targetCopyView.text = "jjkkj"
```

Comment: I actually want to create snapshot view and I want to show the change I made in the original view here. for example, targetView is a UITextField, and I want to create a snapshot view of it and show what I wrote in targetview with textFieldDidChange on snapshot view.@matt

Comment: so I want to see what I wrote on the original TextField on the one I created with snapshotView. @matt

Comment: “show what I wrote in targetview with textFieldDidChange on snapshot view.“ Well you can’t. What you want is not a snapshot but another text view.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can get subview textField

```
 if  let t = targetCopyView.subviews.first(where: { ($0 is UITextField) }) as? UITextField  {
            t.text = "your text"
        }
```